# Android JSON Data not Displayed in ListView ( Using Realm )

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing, realm

im trying to get data from a server inform of JSON and im storing the data to my offline database ( in this case : Realm ), whenever i try to retrieve the data, nothing is displayed in the listview.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static ListView myList;
    public static ListAdapter myAdapter;
    public static Realm realm;


    @Override
    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Realm.init(this);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Recipe> dRecipies = realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll();
        if(dRecipies!= null)dRecipies.deleteAllFromRealm();

    }
});
        DownloadTask newTask = new DownloadTask();
        newTask.execute("hi");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Recipe_list);

       // getData();

        setDisplay();

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String p = String.valueOf(position);
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreenDetails.class);
                in.putExtra("Position", p);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

    }

    public void setDisplay(){

        ArrayList<Recipe> finalRecipies = new ArrayList<>();
        RealmResults<Recipe> rrRecipies = realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll();

        for(Recipe r: rrRecipies){
            finalRecipies.add(r);
            Toast.makeText(this, r.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        myAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, finalRecipies);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        realm.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

im doing this because, if i dont, the data keeps getting repeatedly stored, resulting in repetition.

```
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Recipe> dRecipies = realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll();
        if(dRecipies!= null)dRecipies.deleteAllFromRealm();

    }
});
```

when i tried without actually deleting the data, then the Toast in the
setDisplay() method is working and the data is being shown.(Toasts are repeated as i open the app second time, it gets twice... etc)
When i insert this, even the toasts dont show up.

My download activity

```
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    private RealmList<Recipe> realmRecipe = new RealmList<>();
    String result;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        result = "";
        Realm realm = null;
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json").build();
                    try {
                        result = client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
                        Log.i("RESULT", result);
                        JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject tempObject = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jIngredients = tempObject.getJSONArray("ingredients");
                            JSONArray jSteps = tempObject.getJSONArray("steps");

                            // Get the ingredients
                            List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jIngredients.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject tempIngredient = jIngredients.getJSONObject(j);
                                Ingredients nIngredient = realm.createObject(Ingredients.class);
                                nIngredient.setIngredient(tempIngredient.getString("ingredient"));
                                nIngredient.setMeasure(tempIngredient.getString("measure"));
                                nIngredient.setQuantity(tempIngredient.getString("quantity"));
//                                Ingredients newIngredient = new Ingredients(tempIngredient.getString("quantity"),
//                                        tempIngredient.getString("measure"),
//                                        tempIngredient.getString("ingredient"));
//                                ingredients.add(newIngredient);
                                ingredients.add(nIngredient);
                            }

                            // Get the steps
                            List<Steps> steps = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jSteps.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject tempStep = jSteps.getJSONObject(j);
                                Steps nStep = realm.createObject(Steps.class);
                                nStep.setDescription(tempStep.getString("description"));
                                nStep.setId(tempStep.getString("id"));
                                nStep.setShortDescription(tempStep.getString("shortDescription"));
                                nStep.setVideoURL(tempStep.getString("videoURL"));
                                steps.add(nStep);
//                                Steps newStep = new Steps(tempStep.getString("id"), tempStep.getString("shortDescription"),
//                                        tempStep.getString("description"), tempStep.getString("videoURL"));
//                                steps.add(newStep);
                            }

                            // Create the recipe

                            Recipe nRecipe = realm.createObject(Recipe.class);
                            nRecipe.setId(tempObject.getString("id"));
                            nRecipe.setName(tempObject.getString("name"));
                            nRecipe.setServings(tempObject.getString("servings"));
                            nRecipe.setIngredients(ingredients);
                            nRecipe.setSteps(steps);
                            realmRecipe.add(nRecipe);
//                            Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe(tempObject.getString("id"), tempObject.getString("name"), tempObject.getString("servings"), ingredients, steps);
//                            MainActivity.mRecipies.add(newRecipe);

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.i("Error Message", e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/chsvk/Udacity_Baking                        for further insight into the code

Comment: You may have parsing exception. Is there any message in Logcat which has tag "Error Message"?

Comment: No everything is getting parsed right, but the problem is the data gets repeated each time i run the app, im unable to clear the data after its downloaded the first time

Comment: You don't have to delete the data..just add a primary key in your model class..so that if data is repeated, then instead of inserting , update it..

Comment: i got what you are saying,but can you please show or provide me with an example?

Comment: You're getting duplication because you didn't set `@PrimaryKey` on your `id` fields...